# Can anyone explain this probability law to me?

Tags: probability

I have difficult to understand the following law. Can anyone explain it to me using a simple example that can be understood by an 8th grade student.

> Let $A_1, A_2, \ldots, \text{ and } A_n$ be mutually exclusive and exhaustive events. Then for any other event $B$
>
> $$P(B)=P(A_1B_1) + P(A_2B_2) + \cdots + P(A_nB_n) \enspace. $$

I assume that $P(A_1B_1)$ is the same as $P(A_1 \cap B_1)$, right? Also, what are $B_1$, $B_2$, $\ldots$, $B_n$? I read information on law of total probability in Wikipedia. It is too hard for me to understand.

Comment: Are you sure that both $A$ and $B$ are indexed in the equation. It would seem to me that the equation should be $$P(B) = P(A_1 B)+P(A_2 B) + P(A_3 B).$$ Also, you are correct about $$P(A_1 B_1) = P(A_1 \cap B_1),$$ it's just quicker and neater to omit the intersection sign. If what I've written is correct, I can answer your question, otherwise, please elaborate on the context.

Comment: @David，  both A and B are indexed in the equation, but they could be wrong because I noticed some errors in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Law of total probability easily appeals to intuition and not difficult to understand. Let $A$ be the statement (an event) that some email I receive tomorrow will invite me for a party.   Let $B_1, B_2, B_3$ denote the events that an email I received was sent  (1)  before breakfast (2) between breakfast and lunch  (3) after lunch.

Now as the 3 cases of time durations are exclusive and cover all possibilities.

So the prob of email invitation for a party is the sum of probability of email invitation sent before breakfast plus probability of email invitation sent between breakfast and lunch plus probability of email invitation sent after lunch.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is the book is wrong. We need for the sets that we break $B$ up into to "partition" the original set $B$. That is, we need to be sure that when we split $B$ we have sets $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that $$B = \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i \text{ and } B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset, i \neq j.$$ The reasons we do that are so that we can split up the probability of $B$ into simpler pieces. By the equality in the sets, we have that $$P(B) = P\left(\bigcup_iB_i\right)$$ and by the mutual exclusivity, we can break up the union into a summation, i.e., $$P\left(\bigcup_iB_i\right) = \sum_iP(B_i)$$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity for details). Now, this works for any sets $B_i$ that partition $B$. In particular, we can consider sets which partition our ENTIRE sample space, let's call our sample space $S$ and this partition of $S$ would be $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ where $$S = \bigcup_iA_i.$$ I'm not sure how familiar you are with basic set theory, but we can now consider the intersections $B\cap A_i.$ Since, for any element in $B$, we know that it must fall in some set $A_i$ (because these cover the entire sample space), we have that $$B = \bigcup_iBA_i.$$ Therefore, we can compute the probability of $B$ using the identity I listed above. Namely, $$P(B) = P\left(\bigcup_iBA_i\right) = \sum_iP(BA_i).$$

So what is a practical example of this. Let's say that we wanted to know the probability that people are unhealthy, call this $P(B)$, but we only had a survey to determine this probability from. In particular, the survey asks: (1), do you see a doctor, and (2) are you healthy. The results are given that 1000 people were surveyed and 300 people answered that they see a doctor and are unhealthy and 100 people answered that they do not see a doctor and are unhealthy. Now, because we have that everybody either sees a doctor or does not see a doctor, these sets cover the entire sample space, i.e., if $A_1 := \text{sees doctor}$ and $A_2 := \text{doesn't see doctor}$ then $S = A_1 \cup A_2.$ Additionally, a person can't see a doctor AND not see a doctor, i.e., $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$. So we have that these two sets partition the entire sample space. So, in order to find $P(B)$ we can instead consider $$P(B) = P(BA_1)+P(BA_2) = \frac{300}{1000} + \frac{100}{1000} = \frac{2}{5}.$$